# IL Opcode Modification

Tags: .net, vb.net, il, opcodes

Language: VB.NET 3.5

IL opcodes:

```
    718 ldarg.0 
    719 callvirt    System.Windows.Forms.Button RClient.RClient::get_cmd1()
    724 ldarg.0 
    725 ldfld       System.String[] RClient.RClient::ButtonStrings
    730 ldc.i4.5    
    731 ldelem.ref  
    732 callvirt    System.Void System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase::set_Text(System.String)
    737 ldarg.0
```

Corresponds to:

```
Me.cmd1.Text = Me.ButtonStrings(5)
```

At least I believe it does. 
What changes to the IL would I have to make to reflect this instead:

```
Me.cmd1.Text = "some string"
```

Comment: *Always* write the code first, then use Ildasm.exe to see what IL the VB compiler generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ldarg.0 
callvirt    System.Windows.Forms.Button RClient.RClient::get_cmd1()
ldstr      "some string"
callvirt    System.Void System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase::set_Text(System.String)
```

Line 1 pushes `Me` onto the stack. Line 2 executes the method `get_cmd1` which corresponds to the getter for the property `cmd1` for the object on the top of the stack. So, this line pushes the result of the getter `cmd1` from the object on the top of the stack, popping the top of the stack in the process. Line 3 pushes the string `"some string"` on the stack. At this point the top of the stack is the string `"some string"` and the next item on the stack is `Me.cmd1`. Line 4 executes the method `set_Text` with string parameter being the top of the stack. This corresponds to the setter for `Text` for the second item on the stack. The second item on the stack is `Me.cmd1`. So these lines are equivalent to `Me.cmd1.Text = "some string"`.